# Virtualenv not installing correctly

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x

I had Python 3.4 running on my Windows 8.1 system during which time `virtualenv` used to work correctly.

Due to some requirements not working on 3.4, I downgraded my Python version to Python 2.7.6 by cleanly uninstalling Python 3.4 from `C:\Python34` and installing 2.7 in `C:\Python27`.

Post install of `python`, I installed `pip` and used `pip install virtualenv` to install `virtualenv` for 2.7. However, whenever I run `virtualenv` in my command prompt, I'm faced with the following error:

```
sh.exe": /c/Python34/scripts/virtualenv: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this so that virtualenv uses `python 2.7.6` instead of `3.4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first hunch is to check your PATH variable:

https://superuser.com/questions/502358/easier-way-to-change-environment-variables-in-windows-8

and see if that is still pointing to a now non-existent install. Every time I've installed python on windows, I've had to manually set that, so I wouldn't assume the uninstall would fix it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to install both python 27 and 34 at different folders. You can add 27 folder to system path, and use 34 locally. If you have eclipse with pydev or other IDE tool, just configure pythonpath variable to the corresponding version that you want to use.